# Which clustering method is recommended to start with when all the variables are categorical

Tags: clustering

Which clustering method (k-means, Hierarchical, PCA etc) is recommended to start with when all the predictor variables (16 of them) are categorical, consisting of 3 to 7 levels. I’m assuming k-means most likely isn’t the preferred algorithm, leaving hierarchical or PCA. I just not that familiar with PCA to perform a cluster analysis.

Comment: I would recommend first converting your categorical variables to numeric using one-hot encoding. After that, try K means and see the results. Use within cluster distance or inter cluster distance to judge if the clusters formed are good enough.

Comment: ok that's easy enough. I'll try that first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can convert all category variables using encoder or dummies and try. Also, you can apply PCA and find out the new dimensions and pass it to K-Means clusters, this will help you to get a meaningful cluster. I worked one of the projects like this and PCA helps a lot. Basically a dimensional reduction technique.

Answer (score 0):

While there exist algorithms designed for categoricial data such as k-modes, the answer in my opinion is:

### none.

I have yet to see a sound categoricial clustering result that has some nice properties and that provides actual insight into the data that was not long known beforehand. In my opinion, this is less the fault that we didn't try hard enough to find algorithms, but rather due to the nature of such data, which offers little inbetween of "almost the same vector" and "something completely different".

Comment: k-modes was my first option thought